# I'm passing a variable to a function incorrectly and don't see my mistake

Tags: javascript, function

The code might look more complicated than it needs to be I want to pass i into the balm function but it returns undefined because I'm doing it wrong.
Just extra information: This is for the server of a game I'm writing.  Running in console for node.

```
for (i=30;i>=0;i--){
   setTimeout(function balm(i){
      this_sql ="UPDATE game_moblist SET hp = least(max_hp, hp +"+Math.round(i/2)+") WHERE id ="+mobid
      connection.query(this_sql, function(err, rows, fields) {if (err) err=null});
      console.log(this_sql)
      this_sql ="SELECT hp, max_hp FROM  game_moblist WHERE id ="+mobid;   //emite catch all update pointint to hp..
      connection.query(this_sql, function(err, rows, fields) {if (err) throw err;
      socket.emit ('updatemisc',handler,rows);//eval handler using args
      if (rows[0].hp==rows[0].max_hp){
         i=0;
         return i;
      }
      });
   },(31-i)*333);
}
```

here is a simplified version just showing the concept

```
for (i=3;i>=0;i--){
   setTimeout(function foo(i){
      console.log(foo)
   },1000*i);
```

I would expect the following output
"1" after 1000 ms
"2" after 2000 ms
"3" after 3000 ms
EDIT: It worked when I defined the function outside of setTimeout() and then called it like this
setTimeout(balm(i),...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a loop variable `i` declared outside the callback function and expect it to have the right value once the callback is actually executed - it'll have the last value assigned to it instead.

The code below shows the simplest (but not the shortest) solution:

```
function showNumber(n) {
    return function() {
        console.log(n);
    }
}

for (i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
     setTimeout(showNumber(i), 1000 * i);
}
```

In other words, you call a function (that has its parameter "bound" to your loop variable) which then *returns* another function that is the one actually invoked by `setTimeout()`.

There are other ways of doing this, typically with an *Immediately Invoked Function Expression* as shown in @Xander's answer, but the code above demonstrates the solution nicely.

Answer (score 1):

`i` is `0` when the first callback executes and stays that way through the rest of the calls.

You could create a closure to capture the value of `i` at the moment of declaration:

```
for (i = 3; i >= 0; i--){
    function(x) {
        setTimeout(function foo(i){
            console.log(i)
        },1000 * x);
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: actually `i` is 0 - his loop runs backwards ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Variables can not be passed into a function in its declaration.

```
    for (i=3; i>=0; i--) {
        fooLoop(i);
    }

    function fooLoop(iterator) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("value of i is" + iterator);
        }, 1000*iterator);
    }
```